# ASP.NET Core accessing static files from Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a custom folder where I store my documents and declared it as a static file in my Startup.cs like this.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(RepositoryManager.GetBasePath()),
    RequestPath = RepositoryManager.GetRequestPath()
});

public static string GetBasePath()
{
    var relativePath = @"../../DS/DS.Repository/Repositories";
    var absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
    return absolutePath;
}

public static string GetRequestPath()
{
    return "/Repositories";
}
```

When I save my document, my generated link looks like this:

~/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG

However, when I access it from the ui located in the Documents Area:

```
"data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
    var url =  "~/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG";
    return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data.Name+"</i></a>"
}, "name": "Name"
```

The url ends up looking like this:

https://localhost:44325/Documents/~/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG

How can I fix it so that the relative path links to my file?

Comment: Is that `@Url.Content` helper available like this: `var url =  "@Url.Content("~/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG")";`? Does the path directly passed from controller action as virtual path as mentioned in `url`?

Comment: Your solution works! However, my link is a variable from the server so this doesn't work var url = "@Url.Content(data.Link)"; How can I change this?

Comment: So you want to tell that the link coming from AJAX response, right? By looking from `function (data, type, row, meta)` I think you're using certain jQuery plugin, sounds like `DataTables`.

Comment: Yeah i'm using datatables.

Comment: Thats okay. I can do this serverside instead

Comment: Using string concatenation e.g. `'@Url.Content("~/Repositories/Sample")' + data.Link` or using placeholder `replace()` may be useful if `data.Link` contains file name, because the file name is passed client-side and you can't use it inside the helper. But if full path is present, just concatenate the path instead.